# getSelectedRow on a combobox cell editor

Tags: java, swing, jtable, itemlistener

I need a listener on a CombobBox which is a cellEditor on a JTable.
This listener must give me the new selected value and the row id.

Problem with my below solution is that the listner is linked to all rows, so when I change one ComboBox value in one row, then move to another row (with a different combo value) an event is raised, but the selected row has not yet changed. How can I get rid of this case ?

Thanks

```
column = jTableCheck.getColumnModel().getColumn(9);
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(comboGenre);
    comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                int row = jTableCheck.getSelectedRow();
                Popup.info(e.getItem() + " SELECTED, row="+row);
            }
        }
    });
column.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I already used a TableCellListener on another table, but forgot about that!

I found out a usefull class here: http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an ItemListener on the combo box.

Instead you should be using a `TableModelListener`. An event will be fired whenever the data in the TableModel is changed. So you add the TableModelListener to the TableModel of your JTable.

The TableModelEvent will give your row/column of the cell that changed. You can get the changed value from the TableModel.

Or maybe you would want to use a [Table Cell Listener](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/) which is similar to the TableModelListener except the code is only invoked when the value is actually changed and you use an Action to do the processing.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out when I have time.